# DNS entry works in linux but not on windows - dnsmasq

Tags: windows, dns, dnsmasq

I have dnsmasq setup to serve some home domain names, things like `mqtt`, `node-red` and so on to make managing my home network easier. I have it setup and working fine - except on windows...

My hosts file looks like this:

```
192.168.86.100  mqtt
192.168.86.100  zigbee2mqtt
```

and on linux I can do:

```
nslookup mqtt
Server:         192.168.86.1
Address:        192.168.86.1#53

Name:   mqtt
Address: 192.168.86.100
```

but on windows I get:

```
C:\>nslookup mqtt
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.86.1

*** UnKnown can't find mqtt: Non-existent domain
```

and I really can't understand why!!!

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Is Windows connected to your router and is your router using your Linux dnsmasq server for local DNS?

Comment: yes and yes. You can see that they are both using the same server for resolution - 192.168.86.1 (or am I mis-reading that?)